# Save video livestream on the fly to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, bubble.io

I create app on bubble.io. I need to have video livestream. I want it to be saved on the fly on Amazon S3 bucket. Is it possible to make saving of the video directly into S3 bucket, apart from Bubble DB?

Comment: Hello, are you able to livestream and store the video to an S3 bucket? If that's the case, could you please advise and assist me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The simplest way would probably be to use Kinesis Video Streams to ingest the video, and have that perhaps trigger a lambda function. The lambda function could read fragments from the event and write them to S3.

Note: I haven't used bubble.io so I can't comment on that but it sounds like you are primarily asking about the backend architecture setup.

Comment: I went through and discovered that the flutter sdk for kinesis is not available. Can you assist me in obtaining documentation on how to go about implementing the same? I read the kinesis documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html.
If you have any examples of your work that you could provide, that would be fantastic.